# Visual basic clamping a number

Tags: visual-studio-2013, basic

In Visual Basic, I need a way to clamp a number, preventing it from becoming too small or large.  It has to fit one line, so should ideally look something like this  clamp(x,min,max).  I've tried finding a way to do this but could not find anything, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: my VB is probably terrible, so i'm not even going to try and write it in VB, but in most .NET languages you could do something like this : `double clamp(double x, double min, double max) {  return Math.min(Math.max(x, min),max) }`

Answer (score 0):

try this: (true if a change has been made, and false otherwise)

```
Function clamp(ByRef myNum as Integer, min as Integer, max as Integer) as Boolean
    If myNum < min Then
        myNum = min
        Return True
    End If
    If myNum > max Then
        myNum = max
        Return True
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: So in my code, I can put clamp(variable), and it will perform the code above, on the variable?

Comment: yes. as you can see `myNum` is integer, but you can change it if you want. the call will look like: `isChanged = clamp(myNum, 2, 5)` and `myNum` will be updated between 2 and 5.